# Probability that $m-1$ intervals are not overlapped with one interval

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given a set of intervals $S=\lbrace s_1,s_2,\dots ,s_m\rbrace$. all the intervals have the same length. 
The intervals are randomly placed within $[0,T]$, that is the start point of each interval is randomly selected within $[0,T]$. I am interested in what follows:

1. considering the $s_1$ interval, what the probability that all other intervals $S\setminus \lbrace s_1\rbrace$ are not overlapped with $s_1$?
2. what is the probability that at least two intervals are overlapped with $s_1$?

please help:)
Thank you

Comment: I assume starting point are uniformly randomly taken from [0,T] (they could be randomly taken with another distribution), and that the length is delta
Consider the start of the first interval to be s1, then any other interval si will overlap with it (call it event A) if s1-delta < si < s1+delta, or in other words will overlap with probability
P(A)=P(max(0,s1-delta) < si < min(T,s1+delta))

Comment: I Got The answer:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is somewhat like a problem that involves binomial distributions, but not quite (and is interesting) because of the two boundaries. Let $x_i$ be the starting point of the interval $s_i$ of length $d$.  Let $N$ be the number of intersections.

For the first part of the question, the probability of another interval intersecting $s_1$ depends on the value of $x$. The easy case is when $x \in (d,T-d)$.  Then each of the other $m-1$ intervals has a probability of $\frac{T-2d}{T}$ of not intersecting.  However, when $x \in (0,d)$, then for each, the probability of non-intersection for each of the others is $\frac{T-(x+d)}{T}$.  When $x \in (T-d,T)$, then for each, the probability of non-intersection for each of the others is $\frac{x-d}{T}$.  The probability of zero intersections is 
$$P(N=0)=\int_0^d \left(\frac{T-(x+d)}{T}\right)^{m-1} dx +
\int_d^{T-d} \left(\frac{T-2d}{T}\right)^{m-1} dx +
\int_{T-d}^T \left(\frac{x-d}{T}\right)^{m-1} dx\\
=\frac{1}{T^{m-1}}\left[ (T-2d)^m+\frac{2}{m}\left\{(T-d)^m-(T-2d)^m\right\}\right]$$

For the second part of the question, $$P(N \geq 2)= 1 - P(N=0) - P(N=1)$$  We now only need to determine P(N=1).  Again dividing into 3 cases
$$P(N=1)=\int_0^d (m-1)\frac{x+d}{T}\left(\frac{T-(x+d)}{T}\right)^{m-2} dx +
\int_d^{T-d} (m-1)\frac{2d}{T}\left(\frac{T-2d}{T}\right)^{m-1} dx +
\int_{T-d}^T (m-1)\frac{T-x+d}{T}\left(\frac{x-d}{T}\right)^{m-1} dx$$

Comment: @ammarhowbani Unable to make sense of your latest comment.  But if you found the answer helpful, please leave an upvote.

Comment: I implemented the answer your shared (thanks for you).
I tried with T=5, d=1.
When m=2, Pr(N=0)= 3.2.
When m=4, Pr(N=0)= 1.34
When m=6, Pr(N=0)= 0.59
it is possible to let it normalized between 0-1?